# react.js application showing 404 not found in nginx server

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I uploaded react.js application to a server. I'm using nginx server. Application is working fine. But when I go to another page & refresh, the site is not working. It's showing a 404 Not found error.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 255, accepted):

When your `react.js` app loads, the routes are handled on the frontend by the `react-router`. Say for example you are at `http://a.com`. Then on the page you navigate to `http://a.com/b`. This route change is handled in the browser itself. Now when you refresh or open the url `http://a.com/b` in the a new tab, the request goes to your `nginx` where the particular route does not exist and hence you get 404.

To avoid this, you need to load the root file(usually index.html) for all non matching routes so that `nginx` sends the file and the route is then handled by your react app on the browser. To do this you have to make the below change in your `nginx.conf` or `sites-enabled` appropiately

```
location / {
 try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

This tells `nginx` to look for the specified `$uri`, if it cannot find one then it send `index.html` back to the browser. (See https://serverfault.com/questions/329592/how-does-try-files-work for more details)

Comment: Is there a way to pass to my react app (localhost:3000) rather than to a specific file?

Comment: I hope here the index.html is the one which loads the react app. If you are developing locally then it depends on the development server you use. If you use webpack-dev-server, take a look at `historyFallback` option.

Comment: if still does not work, try this: location / {
 try_files $uri /index.html =404;
}

Comment: For some reason this does not work. Probably there could be something else in the config preventing this. The answer by Ricardo https://stackoverflow.com/a/64815076/3153786 works!

Comment: if you are wondering where to find nginx.conf file, then its located at "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"

Comment: Okay! firs thing first, i was facing the same issue and didnt got resolve as I was doign the chnages in http server block, make sure u do the changes in http server 443 block. thanks me later !!

Comment: This is the most important information for your react app to work. The answered guys must be genius !!

Answer (score 68):

The answers given here are correct. But, I was struggling with this when trying to deploy my `React` Application in a docker container. The problem was on, how to change the `nginx` configs inside a docker container.

**Step 1: Prepare your Dockerfile**

```
# Stage 1
FROM node:8 as react-build
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
RUN yarn
RUN yarn build

# Stage 2 - the production environment
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=react-build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

See line with command: `COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`. Here, we are telling Docker to copy the `nginx.conf` file from the docker host, to the docker container.

**Step 2: Have a `nginx.conf` file in your application root folder**

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri /index.html;                 
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

**Step 3: Now build the docker image and run it**

```
$ docker build . -t react-docker
```

This should build your docker image successfully.
To check that, run

```
$ docker images
```

Now run

```
$ docker run -p 8000:80 react-docker
```

and navigate to http://localhost:8000

This was inspired by [this blog](https://medium.com/greedygame-engineering/so-you-want-to-dockerize-your-react-app-64fbbb74c217).

Comment: Worked for me! perfect!

Comment: This was the answer i was looking for. Worked like a charm.

Comment: you are a life saver ! I took days to figure out why my app stops after refreshing the page ! That's it... my container was missing the instructions to see the static files like index.html...

Comment: I am getting error while build: [app stage-1 2/3] COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
ERROR: failed to calculate checksum of ref 270533d5-xxxxywx: "/nginx.conf": not found

Answer (score 44):

For me the solution was:

```
location / {
            root /var/www/myapp/build;
            index index.html;
            try_files $uri /index.html$is_args$args =404;
    }
```

Comment: You saved my day. Thanks a lot!

Comment: After spending quite a bit of time on this, your solution worked! Can you explain on how this works?

Earlier I had this:
`try_files $uri $uri /index.html;`

When changed to below it worked:
`try_files $uri /index.html$is_args$args =404;`

Comment: This the best solution I found, It worked for me. thank you

Comment: @qwertynik i declared the location that should run application, informed the index file, and the last line (try_files) the nginx always search the URI, but through index.html, else nginx return a error 404.

Comment: Specifying " =404" causes url with parameters my/url&MyParam  to have 404 error.  Without  "=404" `try_files $uri /index.html$is_args$args` works good for me.

Comment: Amazing! This helped me as well... thanks a lot

Comment: This works like magic for nginx server in digitalOcean droplet. Thanks for sharing guy

Comment: @AWEFRANCISOLAWUMI - Thank you man, just MAGIC - https://tenor.com/bN8RV.gif

Comment: Thank you so much, I was stuck on this for more than 2 days. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 11):

After many hours I finally got this working with:

```
try_files $uri /index.html$is_args$args =404;
```

The last arg (=404) is what made this work.

Comment: The answer is the same as [Ricardo Luiz Pereira‘s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64815076/52277), but unfortunately his answer got more votes even if yours was posted earlier.

Comment: why is the `=404` that made it work for you?

Comment: Dude you saved my day. appreciated.

Comment: wouldn't `$is_args` put `?` before the `$args`'s `/`? So they should be reversed?

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me while using nginx to serve react:

Edit the location section of the nginx.conf(or can also be default.conf) file to be as below. The nginx.conf file is found somewhere in /etc/nginx/sites-available/yoursite

```
location / {
   # First attempt to serve request as file, then
   # as directory, then redirect to index(angular) if no file found.
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

The full nginx.conf configuration will therefore be as below:

```
   server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name  localhost;

        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;

        location /{
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes when you are in a path  for eg http:///some/path and you hit refresh you get a 404 error page. This extra line in the ngnix configuration could solve the issue.

```
location /{
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?/$request_uri;
          }
```

After adding do a nginx service restart.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
location /{
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html$is_args$args;
}
```

Comment: Is duplicating “$uri/“ intentional or mistyped?

Answer (score 0):

If your are using nextjs like I am, maybe you need add this to `next.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  trailingSlash: true,
}
```

And build your project again.

For reference:
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/exportPathMap#adding-a-trailing-slash

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/your_domain/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name your_domain www.your_domain;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html  =404;
        } }
```

In location /index.html points to index.html on reload.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and fixed it. I was facing this when I deployed my app on AWS EC2, the App was running but after refers it was showing the error "404 not found".

Solution:
It might be possible that your system or EC2 doesn't have the nginx installed.

**Step 1:** First you need to install the nginx by using the below command:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nginx
```

**Step 2:** Restart the nginx by command `sudo service nginx restart`

**Step 3:** Go to your react app and create a `nginx.conf` file and write the below codes:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri /index.html;                 
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

**Step 4:** Update your dockerfile, and add the `COPY` command to copy the nginx.conf file to `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`. Here are the full `Dockerfile` codes:

```
FROM node:14 as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm i --production
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**Step 5:** Now build your app using whatever technique, whether CI/CD or manually, and see the changes, It will work.

Answer (score -3):

try using following commands in **sites-enabled**

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/Your_WEB_Folder

try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

Get me some towers now!