# React Router routes not working on nginx create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, nginx, react-router, create-react-app

I'm using `"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2"`.

If I test on `localhost:3000/second` it works perfectly.

When I upload this on ubuntu server with nginx and I try `www.website.com`, it works . When I try to use `www.website.com/second` it gives me `404 not found`. I'm using `create-react-app`.

**app.js**

```
class TestRoutes extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    render(){
        return(<React.Fragment>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={MainPage}/>
                    <Route path='/second' component={SecondPage}/>
                    <Route path='/third' component={ThirdPage}/>
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
                </React.Fragment>);
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TestRoutes/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/default**
Here's the configuration file from the server

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;

    root /var/www/reactcamera/build;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name website.com www.website.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/fullchain.pem; # 
    managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/privkey.pem; # 
    managed by Certbot


    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
```

Comment: There are so many things that could be going wrong here. Do you have a redirect to the dist directory that create-react-app makes on yarn build? Did you build? Etc...

Comment: Yes, I cloned it from git and did `npm install` and `npm run build`.

Comment: Can you show your nginx config file

Comment: nginx.conf? So you have it pointing to something when you go to the URL?

Comment: Added the configuration file to the original post.

Comment: Did you restart nginx ? Did you make a link to the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` ?

Comment: I restarted the nginx service by `sudo service nginx restart`. The defult path to `www.website.com` works, but when I type `www.website.com/second` it gives me 404. Do I need to somehow tell the server about each path?

Comment: It seems like React Router shouldn't cause a round trip to the server at all... can this be stymied locally?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The answer is found in this thread
[React-router and nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43951720/react-router-and-nginx)

What I had to do was modify `default` configuration file in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` to:

```
    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
```

Comment: this really nice solution, i have one issue in this post could you check it once it's related to the nginx server integration https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74374786/why-nested-routesreact-router-are-not-working-with-nginix-container-docker-bui

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to do this in a `Dockerfile` and run your `React` app, using `nginx` please see the below answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61753597/4388776

This fixes the `React Router` issues where you allow `nginx` to route traffic coming on different endpoints, directly to you React Application.

Answer (score 0):

**The solution that works for me in the live server:**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/example.com;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
}
```

Comment: please could you check this post its related to nginx configuration i have been facing the same issue with react router https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74374786/why-nested-routesreact-router-are-not-working-with-nginix-container-docker-bui

Answer (score -2):

You need to configure nginx by going /etc/nginx/sites-available/.

There will be a template default file so if you would like to keep it, copy it. After you do that, use any text editor and change /etc/nginx/sites-available/default to following:

```
server {
   listen 80 default_server;
   root /var/www/[Your repo name]/build;
   server_name [your.domain.com] [your other domain if you want to];
   index index.html index.html;
   location / {
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have added the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` to the original post, is there something wrong with my configuration? Do I need to somehow tell the server about each of the paths suchs as `www.website.com/second`?