# why nested routes(react-router) are not working with nginix container docker build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, nginx, react-router

I would like to deploy my project into production, unfortunately I have one blender issue in `react-router` nested router method
I have been trying to resolve this problem for 3 hour, but I could figure it out.
I'm not fully expert in doing docker and nginx configuration

**When I run the project in development it is working fine and even with normal build too.** After all I have noticed the debugging method I let to know that the issue not in the react routers only on **container configuration**.

**Note:** The last time production build was working fine with the same routing method I haven't changed anything in it.

**default.conf**

```
server {
  listen 3000;
  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    expires -1; # Set it to different value depending on your standard requirements
  }
  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:14-alpine as react-build

# => Run container
FROM nginx:1.15.2-alpine
ENV NODE_ENV production
 

COPY package.json /home/node/app
RUN npm install

COPY . /home/node/app
RUN npm run build

# Nginx config
RUN rm -rf /etc/nginx/conf.d
COPY conf /etc/nginx

# Static build
COPY --from=react-build /home/node/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html

# Default port exposure
EXPOSE 3000

# Copy .env file and shell script to container
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./env.sh .
COPY .env .
COPY .env.local .

# Add bash
RUN apk add --no-cache bash

# Make our shell script executable
RUN chmod +x env.sh

#Stream Editor CR LF
RUN sed -i -e 's/\r$//' /usr/share/nginx/html/env.sh

# Start Nginx server
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/usr/share/nginx/html/env.sh && nginx -g \"daemon off;\""]
```

Here is routing file tree

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './Redux/Store/Store';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
```

**app.js**

```
return (
  <>
    <Routes> 
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="/inventory/*" element={<Inventory />} />
      <Route path="/process/*" element={<Process />} />
    </Routes>
  </>
)
```

**Inventory.js**

```
return (
  <>
    <Routes> 
      <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
        <Route index element={<RawItems />} />
        <Route path=":Item/*" element={<Material />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </>
)
```

**Material.js**

```
return (
  <>
    <Routes> 
      <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
        <Route index element={<Cupper />} />
        <Route path="alumin" element={<Aluminium />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </>
)
```

**Issue:** Here is the problem occurred from

**app to Inventory ===> working fine**

**inventory/:Item ====> render the Material.js componet**

**when uri touches this path**

`inventory/:Item/` and `inventory/:Item/alumin` ===> this path are not rendering `Cupper.js` and `Aluminium.js`

What is the issue here why this nested route is not working(inventory/:Item/*)

If it not worked then `why previous nested route working(/inventory/*)`**

I'm totaly confused where the issue was happened. Is it in nginix docker container build or `react-router` implementation problem?

Comment: You say that what you show is your Dockerfile, but it fails at `COPY --from=react-build /home/node/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html` because there's nothing to copy. If you've left out parts of the file, that's important information to share.

Comment: I don't think it's related to your issue, but none of the rendered `Routes` components have a matching closing tag. Is this just a copy/paste typo?

Comment: @DrewReese its my mistake closing tag should be `Routes`, other then that please could you tell is that nested routing impementation is current that what i implemented or did i miss any logic

Comment: I don't see any issue with the routing logic in the app. This appears to be entire an issue on the server serving the app/handling the page requests. The general gist is that the server should be configured to redirect all page requests to the root index.html file. It *looks* like this is what you are trying to do, so you're on the right track IMO, but I lack decent familiarity with docker and nginx so there's not much more I can provide help with.

Comment: @HansKilian i understand what you said, i have forgotten to add the some commands in `Dockerfile` for build commands, i have updated just now that what it has already in my project

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks for the clarification, even I have gotten doubt on two spots like is it in router implementation or in server side ? because i can't do changes without knowing where the problem occur, really thanks i have some clarity now where to work on

Comment: Do you resolve your problem? because i have the same issue(

Comment: @nadia yeah i have resolved this problem, in my case i have some unsafe charectors in the url like ` space, <, >, ", #, %, {, }, |, \, ^, ~, [, ]` so when we deploy with nginix or other they pased that charectors to different format, so our react navigation wont match as we expeched, try to remove that charectors with alternative safe charectors they that worked for me