# Create react app served with nginx and oauth gives me refresh page issue

Tags: reactjs, nginx, oauth, react-router

I have an app that is handled on server by https and it uses Oauth2 with tokens.

In react I have `PathRouter` which redirects to different pages

```
        <Switch>
            {/*the default is devices*/}
            <Route exact path="/">
                <Redirect to="/devices"/>
            </Route>
```

and I have an nginx config

```
server {
    listen 443 http2 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 http2 ssl;
    root /home/path-to-static;
    index index.html;
    
    server_name *****.com;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/debug.log debug;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/*****.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/*****.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ @backend;
      }
                          
    location @backend {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
     }
}
```

And it works!

The trouble starts when I want to refresh the page. Locally (on localhost) it works just fine, but when I refresh page on the server it won't let me and tells me that I am unauthorized.
I have a login screen where I enter my credentials and receive tokens and every request to the server I make with those tokens BUT my routing (I assume that) is the cornerstone that leads to the error- the inner routing happens without tokens.

Once again: it works fine until I refresh the page. Locally it works fine always.

That is the error that is provided on server

[image: nginx error]

PS Maybe this is important: when I logined via login page and then I proceed to devices there is no devices request - as when I refresh the page via F5.

PS 2 I found a config when I am on some tab in my app and I clear all the uri but root and hit enter and it leads me to https://myapp.com/devices ! And it does it correct.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after reading tons of answers on SO I finally got it to work.

Firstly, a great answer from user @Panther here [react.js application showing 404 not found in nginx server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43555282/react-js-application-showing-404-not-found-in-nginx-server)

> When your react.js app loads, the routes are handled on the frontend
> by the react-router. Say for example you are at http://a.com. Then on
> the page you navigate to http://a.com/b. This route change is handled
> in the browser itself. Now when you refresh or open the url
> http://a.com/b in the a new tab, the request goes to your nginx where
> the particular route does not exist and hence you get 404.
>
> To avoid this, you need to load the root file(usually index.html) for
> all non matching routes so that nginx sends the file and the route is
> then handled by your react app on the browser.

So, as he recommended I've changed my config like

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html @backend;
  }
                      
location @backend {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
 }
```

But this gave me some weird errors.

So I have to write location for every path I have, like this:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ @backend;
  }
  
location /devices {        // here my path is similar as in react 
                           // router 
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```