# Page not reload in react

Tags: reactjs

my react page working proper all pages in localhost and if i deploy server side page working fine and again page refresh not loading displayed **404 Not Found** error. how to solve this issue. could you please solve this issue.

Comment: are you using nginx ? .

Comment: Yes, i am using nginx server, error displayed 404 Not Found nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)

Comment: This should help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43555282/react-js-application-showing-404-not-found-in-nginx-server