# Nginx does not recognize all React app routing

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx

I have a react app (create-react-app) that uses `react-router-dom` and it works as expected using docker: on my dev branch I build and run container using the Dockerfile.dev (at bottom), then navigate to /mail where a table of messages displays.

Now I'm trying to run it with nginx, but /mail is not fully rendered - it displays a page with an empty message table (table data comes from /data/Messages.ts along with /data/Config.ts). Also logs do not show a call to /mail (logs below).

Here are my docker commands for prod (nginx):
To build image: `docker build -f Dockerfile.prod -t ui-nginx .`
To run container: `docker run -p 8080:80 ui-nginx`

I tried solutions included [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43011207/using-homepage-in-package-json-without-messing-up-paths-for-localhost) that changed package.json `basename` or passed in ENV PUBLIC_URL=http://localhost:8080/ in the dockerfile but no luck. Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43555282/react-js-application-showing-404-not-found-in-nginx-server/61753597#61753597) that changed nginx.conf config, still no luck

I'm pretty new to nginx. How do I configure nginx navigation to /mail?

docker logs

```
% docker run -p 8080:80 ui-nginx
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packaged version
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2024/02/24 19:35:53 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
2024/02/24 19:35:53 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.24.0
2024/02/24 19:35:53 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 12.2.1 20220924 (Alpine 12.2.1_git20220924-r4) 
2024/02/24 19:35:53 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 6.6.12-linuxkit
2024/02/24 19:35:53 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
2024/02/24 19:35:53 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
2024/02/24 19:35:53 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 29
2024/02/24 19:35:53 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 30
2024/02/24 19:35:53 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 31
2024/02/24 19:35:53 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 32
2024/02/24 19:35:53 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 33
2024/02/24 19:35:53 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 34
2024/02/24 19:35:53 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 35
2024/02/24 19:35:53 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 36
192.168.65.1 - - [24/Feb/2024:19:36:29 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 887 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
192.168.65.1 - - [24/Feb/2024:19:36:29 +0000] "GET /static/js/main.391febc6.js HTTP/1.1" 200 223526 "http://localhost:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
192.168.65.1 - - [24/Feb/2024:19:36:29 +0000] "GET /static/css/main.cb0cc79e.css HTTP/1.1" 200 4141 "http://localhost:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
192.168.65.1 - - [24/Feb/2024:19:36:29 +0000] "GET /manifest.json HTTP/1.1" 200 306 "http://localhost:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

project structure

```
Dockerfile.prod
README.md
docker-compose.prod.yml
nginx
└── nginx.conf
node_modules
package-lock.json
package.json
public
├── delete.png
├── favicon.ico
├── index.html
├── manifest.json
└── robots.txt
src
├── App.css
├── App.test.tsx
├── App.tsx
├── components
│   ├── Box.tsx
│   ├── Button.tsx
│   ├── Checkbox.tsx
│   ├── FlexBox.tsx
│   ├── Footer.tsx
│   ├── Header.tsx
│   ├── Home.tsx
│   ├── Icons
│   │   ├── CellControl.tsx
│   │   └── Delete.tsx
│   ├── Link.tsx
│   ├── Mail
│   │   ├── Mail.tsx
│   │   ├── MailReply.tsx
│   │   ├── MailSent.tsx
│   │   ├── MailView.tsx
│   │   ├── MessageNew.tsx
│   │   ├── MessageReadMetaHeader.tsx
│   │   ├── MessageView.tsx
│   │   └── Table
│   │       ├── Table.tsx
│   │       ├── TableHeaders.tsx
│   │       └── TableRows.tsx
│   ├── NotFound.tsx
│   ├── Select.tsx
│   ├── TextArea.tsx
│   ├── TextAreaImageAdd.tsx
│   ├── TextField.tsx
│   ├── TextFieldImageAdd.tsx
│   └── Typography.tsx
├── data
│   ├── Config.ts
│   ├── Constants.ts
│   ├── Messages.ts
├── index.css
├── index.tsx
├── react-app-env.d.ts
├── reportWebVitals.ts
├── setupTests.ts
├── tests
│   ├── Button.test.tsx
│   ├── Header.test.tsx
│   ├── Home.test.tsx
│   ├── Mail.test.tsx
│   └── Select.test.tsx
├── types
│   └── types.tsx
└── utils
    └── utils.tsx
tsconfig.json
```

nginx.conf

```
server {

  listen 80;

  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }

}
```

Dockerfile.prod

```
FROM node:21-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY public  /app/public
COPY package.json package-lock.json /app/
RUN npm ci
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

App.tsx

```
import './App.css';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { StringConstants } from "./data/Constants";
import { Footer } from './components/Footer';
import { Header } from './components/Header';
import { Home } from './components/Home';
import { MailReply } from "./components/Mail/MailReply";
import { MailSent } from "./components/Mail/MailSent";
import { MailView } from "./components/Mail/MailView";
import { useState } from "react";
import { user } from "./data/Config";
import NotFound from "./components/NotFound";


function App() {
  const [mailFactor, setMailFactor] = useState<number>(-1)
  const [userLoggedIn] = useState<boolean>(false)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header setMailFactor={setMailFactor} userLoggedIn={userLoggedIn} />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={ <Home /> } />
        <Route path="mail" >
          <Route index          element={<MailView title={StringConstants.INBOX} mailFactor={mailFactor} setMailFactor={setMailFactor} />} />
          <Route path="sent"    element={<MailView title={StringConstants.SENT} mailFactor={mailFactor} setMailFactor={setMailFactor} />} />
          <Route path="deleted" element={<MailView title={StringConstants.DELETED} mailFactor={mailFactor} setMailFactor={setMailFactor} />} />
          <Route path="new"     element={<MailView title={StringConstants.BUTTON_TEXT_NEW} mailFactor={mailFactor} setMailFactor={setMailFactor} />} />
          <Route path="send"    element={<MailSent />} />
          <Route path="reply"   element={<MailReply />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path='*'         element={<NotFound />}/>
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Dockerfile.dev

```
FROM node:20-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY public  /app/public
COPY package.json package-lock.json /app/
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

RUN npm ci
COPY . ./

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: React Router routes are handled client side (commonly called a Single Page Application or SPA). They don't send requests to the server when the URL path changes.

Comment: @HansKilian makes sense, thanks for that clarification. So I should not expect a server log entry for /mail. Do you have suggestions for debugging why that table does not populate with data?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was not nginx at all. I was making the mistake of not ensuring my env variables were being read at runtime. I had an env variable that simulated a current user and that value was used to grab messages for that user.